# Change image using multiple button and javascript

Tags: javascript, image, button

I have this code from another stackoverflow question to change image using multiple SELECT and javascript:

```js
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var color = document.getElementById("colour").value;
    var size = document.getElementById("size").value;

    image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color;
};
```

```html
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<select id="colour" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="red.png">Red</option>
    <option value="green.png">Green</option>
</select>

<select id="size" onChange="swapImage()">
    <option value="small">Small</option>
    <option value="large">Large</option>
</select>
```

So, how to change SELECT to BUTTON?

For example:

```js
function swapImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    var color = document.getElementById("colour").value;
    var size = document.getElementById("size").value;

    image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color;
};
```

```html
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<div id="colour" onChange="swapImage()">
  <button value="red.png">Red</button>
  <button value="green.png">Green</button>
</div>

<div id="size" onChange="swapImage()">
  <button value="small">Small</button>
  <button value="large">Large</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like bellow. It's works fine and it's understable for beginners.

```
var color = 'Red';
var size = 'Green';

function changeColor(newColor) {
    color = newColor;
    updateImage();
}

function changeSize(newSize) {
    size = newSize;
    updateImage();
}

function updateImage(){
    var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");
    image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color;
};

<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<div>
  <button value="red.png" onClick="changeColor('Red')">Red</button>
  <button value="green.png" onClick="changeColor('Green')">Green</button>
</div>

<div>
  <button value="small" onClick="changeSize('Small')">Small</button>
  <button value="large" onClick="changeSize('Large')">Large</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve same thing by button as

Here I am calling the function `onclick` of each button . These buttons are inside the `div` having id as `colour` and `size`. taking the attribute of id as color and size are changed

```js
var color = 'red.png';//default values
var size = 'small';//default values

function swapImage(obj) {
  var image = document.getElementById("imageToSwap");


  if (obj.parentElement.getAttribute('id') == "colour") {
    color = obj.getAttribute('value')
  }
  if (obj.parentElement.getAttribute('id') == "size") {
    size = obj.getAttribute('value')
  }


  image.src = "img/" + size + "_" + color;
};
```

```html
<img id="imageToSwap" src="img/red.png">

<div id="colour">
  <button value="red.png" onclick="swapImage(this)">Red</button>
  <button value="green.png" onclick="swapImage(this)">Green</button>
</div>

<div id="size">
  <button value="small" onclick="swapImage(this)">Small</button>
  <button value="large" onclick="swapImage(this)">Large</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!